# How to remove payment method from WooCommerce order confirmation email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, payment-method

We've removed the payment information on our customer emails but can't remove the title. How do we do it?We're using Woocommerce email templates for order confirmation emails.

We've searched in and tried to change

- email-order-details.php
- email-order-items.php
- customer-on-hold-order. php (our customer use on-hold-order as default template for confirmation emails to customers)

We tried this one in
email-order-details, it did not work at all.

```
<tfoot>
    <?php
        if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                $i++;
                if ( $total['label'] != 'Payment Method:' ){
                    ?><tr>
                        <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove payment method from WooCommerce email notifications using hooks:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'remove_paymeny_method_row_from_emails', 10, 3 );
function remove_paymeny_method_row_from_emails( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    // On Email notifications only
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        unset($total_rows['payment_method']);
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Or overriding `email-order-details.php` template file:

```
<tfoot>
    <?php
        if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $totals as $key => $total ) {
                $i++;
                if ( $key !== 'payment_method' ){
                    ?><tr>
                        <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</tfoot>
```

It should also works.

Comment: Thank you for answering, we tried that, it didn't work at first. When we removed old plugin for bank transfer payments it worked fine. Thank you!